# Unable to add privilege to tizen-manifest.xml in Tizen.NET wearable app

Tags: c#, android, samsung-mobile, tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk

I am following the documentation here https://developer.samsung.com/galaxy-watch-develop/creating-your-first-app/net-companion/use-sap.html?fbclid=IwAR3_q-0sBgBXxIC1VkeGAjDItcTJvvaxbPAkbGDSvgJtZvPoLEhszd29cR8 in order to experiment with SAP (Samsung Accessory Protocol). Step 4 says to add a privilege to tizen.manifest.xml however when I attempt to do this, I get an error in Visual Studio 2019 (I'm on Windows 10).  The error is:

```
"Please install baseline SDK to use privilege list".
```

I have then gone and installed the baseline SDK from here https://developer.samsung.com/tizen/blog/en-us/2019/01/16/install-tizen-baseline-sdk and retried with the same error occuring. Even after a restart, and several successful installation attempts/re-attempts. Can someone assist?

Comment: AFAIK, the baseline SDK is just a synonym of Tizen Studio (Tizen SDK). Do you see green checks in [Tools]-[Options...]-[Tizen]-[Tools]? If not, set the tool path to your SDK installation directory (`tizen-studio`).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have correct path to your Tizen Studio installation.
It's in Tools->Options->Tizen->Tools as on the screenshot.
[image]